# MySQL - Trigger before insert, only insert if col = another existing database name?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, dml

I have a database (`database1`) and a table `imei_db(IMEI VARCHAR(15), db VARCHAR(40))`. I also have other databases (ex: `database2`) and I want a trigger that, whe inserting a row on `database1`.`imei_db`, it verifies before the actual insert if there is a database with a name equal to `db` field value.

For example:

Existing databases: `database1, database2`

Succeeds: `INSERT INTO imei_db VALUES ("111222333444555","database2")`

Fails: `INSERT INTO imei_db VALUES ("111222333444555","database3")`

Comment: What is `database3`?

Comment: A possible database that actually does not exist and was just used as an example of failure. On the example it would be a way to say that "for device `111222333444555`, I should use the `database3` to store its data".

Comment: @PM77-1, have you got any ideas on how to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean to verify existence in `SHOW DATABASES` list?

Comment: No, I mean like on the insert query. Only insert if there is a database with that name already. Actually, I've managed to do it; looks a bit low quality, though. I am posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

```
USE database1;
INSERT INTO `imei_db`(`IMEI`,`db`)
SELECT 111222333444555,"database2" FROM anytable
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database2') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'table_expected_to_exist')) = 1
LIMIT 1;
```